# Get cost of initial guess and set cost description

Tags: drake

I understand how to check the constraint satisfaction at initial guess, and how to set a description for constraint. This is using `.evaluator().set_description(` and `prog.CheckSatisfiedAtInitialGuess`.

But how do we do these things for costs?

1. The evaluator.set_description does not work for costs. The name shows up as empty string.
2. How do we check the cost at initial guess without laboriously tracking which variables go into which cost and feeding it into Eval? This adds a lot of extra code when you have a lot of costs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function [MathematicalProgram::EvalBindingAtInitialGuess()](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1solvers_1_1_mathematical_program.html#a0eb46a0ff11d6f6d22d69d9c16bfce94) that can evaluate a binding at the initial guess of the program.

To evaluate the total cost at some initial guess, you can do

```cc
prog.EvalBindings(prog.GetAllCosts(), prog.initial_guess()).sum();
```